# Chrome suggested box is not cleared after onsubmit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I submit a `<form>` in javascript with 'ENTER' key and call a function. This function returns false so that the page is not reloaded.

Unfortunately, the box is not cleared as shown in the picture.

[image: I have just added the 'tot' player at] the end of the list, but 'toto' and other entries were proposed. The suggestion box is not cleared.
How could I clear it?

Here is the code used

```
$('form').on('submit', function () {
    var newUser = $('input.user').val()
    displayPerson(newUser) // add the person
    $('input.user').val('')
    return false;
});
```

Comment: try with `$('input.user').empty()`

Comment: Is this just a suggestion box by Chrome or really the value inside the box?

Comment: I think that's coming from chrome suggestion...do one thing goto incognito mode and check if that suggestion comes or not

For Incognito mode on chrome:
ctrl+shift+n for windows
Cmd+Shift+n for Mac

Comment: it's a suggestion by Chrome. I didn't ask anything or used a jquery plugin

Comment: I tried  `$('input.user').empty()` but it makes the same problem. My 'tot' value is removed from the input, but the suggestion box stays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to briefly remove the focus from the input:

```
$('form').on('submit', function () {
    var newUser = $('input.user').val()
    displayPerson(newUser) // add the person
    $('input.user').val('').blur(); // <-- blur
    setTimeout(function () { // Allow time for blur to happen
        $('input.user').focus(); // <-- put focus back (if desired).
    }, 0);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Perfect. On my chrome, I don't even need the setTimeout, but I think it's cleaner to keep it.